# Redirect in .htaccess if file exists (cache)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I do not understand anything .htaccess and I need a redirection to cache.

Currently use the following rule:
`RewriteRule ^movie/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ app.php?view=movie&theatre=$1&ordem=$2&movie=$3 [L,QSA]`

That is, the requested URL 
`movie/jardins/0/robocop`

redirects to

`app.php?view=movie&theatre={jardins}&ordem={0}&movie={robocop}`

But I want to redirect `api/cache/html/{jardins}/{0}/{robocop}.html` if file exists.

Recalling that {jardins} and {0} are directories.

How to do this? :(

Comment: You can use the [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directive.

Comment: @hjpotter92 like I know :(

Comment: Can you clarify what the file will be and where you want to redirect this file?

Comment: @PanamaJack I'll use an example. The `/movie/jardins/0/robocop` redirects to `app.php?vire=movie&theatre=jardins&ordem=0&movie=robocop`.  Basically, I wanted to redirect it before the `app.php...`, sought in the cache `/api/cache/html/jardins/0/robocop.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/cache/html/$1/$2/$3\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^movie/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ app/cache/html/$1/$2/$3.html [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^movie/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ app.php?view=movie&theatre=$1&ordem=$2&movie=$3 [L,QSA]
```